# wordpress display the navbar menu item vertically

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, codex

This is Y code of `header.php` but I can't understand why `wp_nav_menu` give me a vertical menu.

[image]

This is my code of `header.php`

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" alt="DevtechFreelancer"></a>
            </div>

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'container'         => 'nav',
                    'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
                ) );
            ?>

        </div>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

Please help: I can't find a solution for this bug.

Comment: Seems like your code looks fine per [Bootstrap Navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) except one thing, `container` attribute is a `div` in the bootstrap navbar example.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, if i find a solution i will announce directly

Comment: There's also a chance that Bootstrap CSS file is not loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

```
<?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(

                                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                'container'         => 'ul',
                                'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

                            )   );
                        ?>
```